# Give the system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

A mining company produce in three mines aluminium and zinc. At the following matrix give the information about the amount of zinc and alluminium at a produced tonne of ore and the corresponding cost per tonne of ore:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Mine } & \text{ Zinc } & \text{ Alluminium } & \text{ Cost/ tonne of ore }\\ 
1 & 10\% & 40\% & 60\\ 
2 & 20\% & 30\% & 45\\ 
3 & 30\% & 20\% & 40
\end{matrix}$$

For a specific costumer 100 t of zinc and 200 t of alluminium have to be produced.  We have to give a system of equations, from which the required amounts for the production at each mine  can be computed. We have to give also all the solutions of this system.

I have done the following but I am not really sure if I understood correctly the exercise...

Let $z_i$ be the amount of zinc produced by the mine $i$ and let $a_i$ be the amount of alluminium produced by the mine $i$.

Then do we get the following system?

$$0.1x_1+0.2x_2+0.3x_3=100 \\ 0.4a_1+0.3a_2+0.2a_3=200$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I suppose that you need to minimize the total cost of productiion. The constraints are given in RSerrao's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the problem statement says is that for mine $i $, each tone of ore is $x_i \%$ zinc and $y_i \% $ alluminium, for the tabled values.

Hence if mine $i $ produces $t_i $ tones of ore we have $x_it_i $ zinc and $y_it_i $ alluminium because from each ton of ore, we can extract **both** zinc **and** alluminium.

Therefore your system is not quite right yet.

Can you make it right? Also, what is the cost, in terms of the tons extracted from each mine, to fulfill that order?

You may want to start by assuming each mine produced $t_i $ tons of ore and then calculating how much zinc and how much alluminium that makes up.

Using your own table, we have

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Mine } & \text{ Zinc } & \text{ Alluminium } & \text{ Cost/ tonne of ore }\\ 
1 & 10\% & 40\% & 60\\ 
2 & 20\% & 30\% & 45\\ 
3 & 30\% & 20\% & 40
\end{matrix}$$

so we just rename the 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns to

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{(Mine)}\ i & x_i & y_i & \text{ Cost/ tonne of ore }\\ 
1 & 10\% & 40\% & 60\\ 
2 & 20\% & 30\% & 45\\ 
3 & 30\% & 20\% & 40
\end{matrix}$$

Therefore if, for example, mine 1 produces $10$ tons of ore, $t_1 = 10$, we have $x_110 = 0.1\cdot10 = 1$ ton of zinc.

We now say that mines 1, 2 and 3 produced $t_1, t_2$ and $t_3$ tons of ore. We can write this table:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Tons produced in mine}\ i & \text{ Amount of zinc } & \text{ Amount of alluminium } & \text{ Total cost of production }\\ 
t_1 & x_1t_1 & y_1t_1 & t_160\\ 
t_2 & x_2t_2 & y_2t_2 & t_245\\ 
t_3 & x_3t_3 & y_3t_3 & t_340
\end{matrix}$$

But we need that the total zinc produced be $100$ tons and the total alluminium be $200$ tons therefore we must have:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1t_1 + x_2t_2 + x_3t_3 = 100\\
y_1t_1 + y_2t_2 + y_3t_3 = 200
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I got stuck right now... We have that for a specific costumer 100 t of zinc and 200 t of alluminium have to be produced, so do we have that $x_i=100$ and $y_i=200$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar check my edited answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: So, do we have the following system? $$\begin{cases}
0.1t_1 + 0.2t_2 + 0.3t_3 = 100\\
0.4t_1 + 0.3t_2 + 0.2t_3 = 200
\end{cases}$$ or not?

Comment: @MaryStar yes that is right

Comment: I see... After that there is the following question: $$$$ 
"At the table we can see also the costs for the production and the separation of the metals per tonne of ore. What amounts does it have to be produced in each mine so that the costs are minimal? Which are the minimal costs? " $$$$ To find that we have to find the values for $t_i$ so that $t_160+t_245+t_340$ is minimal, or not? How can we compute this?

Comment: @MaryStar That is right. To compute it, you should use any of the methods you know to find the optimal solution for a problem like this: a problem on linear optimization.

Comment: So we want to compute $\min \ t_160+t_245+t_340$ . Which are the constraints for the variables? The same as the one of the previous question? Or aren't there constraints?

Comment: @MaryStar the constraints are the same because we want to know the minimal cost to fulfill the shipment the costumer wants. Do you understand?

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar i saw your other comments but didnt have the chance to answer. Do you still have any doubts?

Comment: I made a mistake... Do we have the following? 
$$0.1x_1+0.2x_2+0.3x_3=100 \\ -0.5x_2-x_3=-200$$ 
The solutions are $$(x_1, x_2, x_3)=(-0.5x_2+400, x_2, -0.5x_2+200)$$ 
where $-0.5x_2+400\geq 0\Rightarrow 0.5x_2\leq 400 \Rightarrow x_2\leq 800$, $x_2\geq 0$ and $-0.5x_2+200\geq 0 \Rightarrow 0.5x_2\leq 200 \Rightarrow x_2\leq 400$.  
So, it must be $0\leq x_2\leq 400$. 
The cost is $$\text{ Cost } =60x_1+45x_2+40x_3=60(-0.5x_2+400)+45x_2+40(-0.5x_2+200)=32000-5x_2, \ 0\leq x_2\leq 400 $$

Comment: $32000-5x_2$ has its minimal value when $x_2$ gets its maximal value. So, we have that the cost is minimal when $x_2=400$,so when $(x_1, x_2, x_3)=(200, 400, 0). $
That means that in the mine $1$ $\ 200\cdot 0.1=20$ tonnes of zirc and $200\cdot 0.4=80$ tonnes of aluminium will be produced,  in the mine $2$ $\ 400\cdot 0.2=80$ tonnes of zirc and $400\cdot 0.3=120$ tonnes of aluminium and in the mine $3$ $\ 0\cdot 0.3=0$ tonnes of zirc and $0\cdot 2=0$ tonnes of aluminium. 
The minimal cost is $$\text{ Cost } =32000-5\cdot 400=3000 $$ 
Is it correct now?